# Auto adjust numbers in jquery on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need jquery solution which needs to be auto adjusted with corresponding data attribute on clicking button.

```html
<input type="number"><button>Auto adjust</button> the value entered!
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<tr>
<td>8</td>
<td><input type="number"></td>
</tr>
<br>
The data should be ajusted with coressponding table value when given higher values.
```

Answer (score 0):

I add two `id` attribute to inputs for show what I meaning better:

```
<input type="number" id="input"><button>Auto adjust</button> the value entered!
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<tr>
<td>8</td>
<td><input type="number" id="tableInput"></td>
</tr>
<br>
```

use form this below script:

```
$('button').on('click' , () => {
    let inputVal = $("#input").val();
    $("#tableInput").val(inputVal);
})
```